# Using amazon mqtt to publish a button press from a esp8266

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, esp8266, mongoose-os

I have the following code that prints to my serial console in mongoose os. I can see the device in amazon aws, and in mdash as online. I get back a 0 from the pub and it never sends a message to aws mqtt I have subscribed to the topic in the test seciton in mqtt so not sure what I am doing wrong

```
load("api_gpio.js");
load("api_mqtt.js");
load("api_sys.js");
let pin = 0;
GPIO.set_button_handler(
  pin,
  GPIO.PULL_UP,
  GPIO.INT_EDGE_NEG,
  50,
  function (x) {
    let topic = "mOS/topic1";
    let message = JSON.stringify({
      total_ram: Sys.total_ram(),
      free_ram: Sys.free_ram(),
    });
    let ok = MQTT.pub(topic, message, message.length);
    let test = ok;
    let res = MQTT.pub("mOS/topic1", JSON.stringify({ a: 1, b: 2 }), 1);

    print(res);
    print("Published:", res ? "yes" : "no");
  },
  true
);
print("Flash button is configured on GPIO pin", pin);
print("Press the flash button now!");

MQTT.sub(
  "mOS/topic1",
  function (conn, topic, msg) {
    print("Topic:", topic, "message:", msg);
  },
  null
);
```

I am pretty sure I have fullfilled all these requirments

A valid connection

A valid and active certificate

A policy that allows the desired connection and operation

I have a mos-default policy with the following

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ],
  "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

There is a mos.yml file of the following. And I do have aws.crt.pem and aws.key.pem files in the app.

```
author: mongoose-os
description: A JS-enabled demo Mongoose OS firmware
# arch: PLATFORM
version: 1.0
manifest_version: 2017-05-18
libs_version: ${mos.version}
modules_version: ${mos.version}
mongoose_os_version: ${mos.version}

config_schema:
  - ["mqtt.server", "iot.eclipse.org:1883"]
  - ["i2c.enable", true]

tags:
  - js

filesystem:
  - fs

libs:
  - origin: https://github.com/mongoose-os-libs/boards
  - origin: https://github.com/mongoose-os-libs/js-demo-bundle

conds:
  # It's not that we can't work with multicore
  # but we cannot afford it because of space (32K).
  - when: mos.platform == "esp32"
    apply:
      build_vars:
        ESP_IDF_SDKCONFIG_OPTS: >
          ${build_vars.ESP_IDF_SDKCONFIG_OPTS}
          CONFIG_FREERTOS_UNICORE=y
```

```
let connected = MQTT.isConnected();

print(connected);
```

returns false, I am not sure how to debug this

I followed every instruction here including the internet button video
https://mongoose-os.com/docs/mongoose-os/cloud/aws.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it is working again, I needed to delete the device in amazon, and run the mos aws setup command again.

So the real problem was I was flashing my device each time I updated my code and it would overwrite my wifi settings, my aws settings and my mdash settings.

Thanks to help from a different [source](https://community.mongoose-os.com/t/using-amazon-mqtt-to-publish-a-button-press-from-a-esp8266/1827/5) this solved it for me

```
Use mos call FS.List to get a directory listing of the files in your device
Use mos get to retrieve your credentials and save them locally in your fs dir.
E.g.:

$ mos get aws-esp32_807A98.key.pem > fs/aws-esp32_807A98.key.pem
$ mos get aws-esp32_807A98.crt.pem > fs/aws-esp32_807A98.crt.pem
$ mos get ca.pem > fs/ca.pem
Use mos config-get to read your config, or just copy from that verbose output you get when you initialize your device. Save those to mos.yml.
E.g.:

["aws.thing_name", ""]
["mqtt.enable", true]
["mqtt.server", "a1234b5678cde-ats.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:8883"]
["mqtt.ssl_ca_cert", "ca.pem"]
["mqtt.ssl_cert", "aws-esp32_807A98.crt.pem"]
["mqtt.ssl_key", "aws-esp32_807A98.key.pem"]
So, when you re-flash, you re-write your credentials and configure your device with the same data again.
```